# Mach number: understanding incompressibility through acoustic time scale

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, kinetic-theory

In the past I have always recognized the mach number as being the ratio between the bulk velocity of a fluid $v$ in relation to the speed of sound in that medium. I have also seen how one can derive this non-dimensional quantity by non-dimensionalizing the continuity equation in which it becomes trivial that as $\mathrm{Ma} \rightarrow 0$ then the continuity equation for incompressibility is retrieved.

However, reading a book recently made another definition by comparing the acoustic time scale to the the advective time scale (as a ratio) to derive at the exact same expression. I understand that advective time scale is related to the bulk motion of the fluid and that the acoustic time scale is related to the speed of sound. However, I can't really find a good explanation as to why when the acoustic time scale is much faster than the advective time scale then we expect incompressible flow. How can one relate the idea of how fast pressure waves propagate in a fluid to it's compressibility?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with the analysis of Euler equations (limit of Navier--Sotkes equations, for vanishing viscosity), as a hyperbolic system of equations, from a mathematical point of view? Anyway, when we add the incompressibility constraint, we're giving up thermodynamics